# Live form validation using with jQuery/Coffee AJAX Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, coffeescript

Okey, so I have this problem... And I've had it for like weeks. I'm working on a school project and I'm supposed to make a live form validation using Ruby on rails and ajax (jQuery/Coffee). I've google my arse off and I've found loads and loads of plugins for it, but not one helpful tutorial. I've got some code together that seems legit, but I need help to make this code validate the form live, checking the database for email, username etc. It's for the sign up page so I think you get the idea.

```
$("#new_user").live "ajax:beforeSend", (event, xhr, status) ->
        form = $(this)
        form.validate {

        # Validations goes here, but how do I write it?

        }

        false unless form.valid()
```

So I guess I'm suppose to write a controller to handle the validations through this jQuery. I'm really new to both Rails and Ajax, so please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Your school project will probably be due by now, but here goes anyway.

Check out https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.

If you use this, you don't need to worry about writing javascript to validate your form. You just need to worry about writing the correct validations in your model.

This might help get you started http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations.

Also if you are new to rails you should know that for most common problems and for a lot of not so common problems there is a solution in the form of a gem.

So if you need to write sign-in/sign-up functionality you might want to check out https://github.com/plataformatec/devise. Which also has a railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise.

Finally here is wiki page that explains how to make `client_side_validations`and `simple_form` work together https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/wiki/Using-Devise.

Hope this helps.